# store data issue with generic grid rendered in tabs

Tags: extjs

I have a generic grid component. 
on click of menu item corresponding grid is displayed in independent tabs.
on rendering the grid component, store data is set dynamically and grid is populated.
The problem if I open two grids in two tabs, on navigating to the first tab, grid data is not displayed as the store data is set to second grid data.

Hoping to find solution.Thank you

code in main controller:

```
OnMenuItemClick: function(c){
        var nodeText = c.text,
        tabs = Ext.getCmp('app-tab'),
        tabBar = tabs.getTabBar(),
        tabIndex;
        for(var i = 0; i < tabBar.items.length; i++) {
            if (tabBar.items.get(i).getText() === nodeText) {
            tabIndex = i;
            }
        }    
        if (Ext.isEmpty(tabIndex)) {          
          /* Note: While creating the Grid Panel,here we are passing the Menu/Grid Id along with it for future reference */
          tabs.add(Ext.create('DemoApp.view.grid.GenericGrid',{title:nodeText,gridId:c.id,overflowY: 'scroll',closable:true}));
          tabIndex = tabBar.items.length - 1 ;
       }
        tabs.setActiveTab(tabIndex);         
    }
```

code in generic grid controller:

```
renderGridMetadata: function(genericGrid) {
          var store = Ext.getStore("DemoApp.store.GenericGrid"),
              gridId = genericGrid.up().gridId,
              resourceURL = "resources/data/" + gridId + ".json";
          var serviceInput = Util.createServiceResponse(gridId);
          /*Dynamically add the proxy URL to the ViewModel
         DemoApp.model.GenericGrid.getProxy().setUrl(resourceURL);*/
          Ext.getBody().mask("Loading... Please wait...", 'loading');
          Ext.Ajax.request({
              url: Util.localGridService,
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                  'SM_USER': 'arun.x.kumar.ap@nielsen.com',
                  'SM_SERVERSESSIONID': 'asdfadsf'
              },
              jsonData: {
                  getConfigurationAndDataRequestType: serviceInput
              },
              success: function(conn, response, options, eOpts) {
                  Ext.getBody().unmask();
                  var data = Util.decodeJSON(conn.responseText);
                  /* Apply REST WebServices response Metadata to the Grid */
                  var recordsMetaData = data.getConfigurationAndDataReplyType.gridConfigDataResponse.data.record;
                  var jsonMetaDataArray = [];
                  for (var c = 0; c < recordsMetaData.length; c++) {
                      var jsonMetaDataObject = {};
                      var text = data.getConfigurationAndDataReplyType.gridConfigDataResponse.data.record[c].displayName;
                      var dataIndex = data.getConfigurationAndDataReplyType.gridConfigDataResponse.data.record[c].columnName;
                      jsonMetaDataObject["text"] = text;
                      jsonMetaDataObject["dataIndex"] = dataIndex;
                      jsonMetaDataArray.push(jsonMetaDataObject);
                  }
                  /* Apply REST WebServices response data to the Grid */
                  var recordsData = data.getConfigurationAndDataReplyType.gridDataResponse.record;
                  var jsonDataArray = [];
                  for (var r = 0; r < recordsData.length; r++) {
                      var columnsData = data.getConfigurationAndDataReplyType.gridDataResponse.record[r].column;
                      var jsonDataObject = {};
                      for (var c = 0; c < columnsData.length; c++) {
                          jsonDataObject[columnsData[c].columnId] = columnsData[c].columnValue;
                      }
                      jsonDataArray.push(jsonDataObject);
                  }
                  store.setData(jsonDataArray);
                  genericGrid.reconfigure(store, jsonMetaDataArray);
              },
              failure: function(conn, response, options, eOpts) {
                  Ext.getBody().unmask();
                  Util.showErrorMsg(conn.responseText);
              }
          });
          store.load();
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely there is only one instance of DemoApp.store.GenericGrid.

Frankly, I only guess because I see that you call `Ext.getStore("DemoApp.store.GenericGrid")` that implies the store is declared in `stores:["DemoApp.store.GenericGrid"]` array probably in the application class.

If a store is declared this way then Ext automatically creates one instance of it setting storeId to the string listed in `stores:[]`. Hence, `Ext.getStore()` returns that instance.

If you want to have two independent instances of the grid you have to create store instances yourself preferably in `initComponent` override.

Comment: I used Ext.create('DemoApp.store.GenericGrid') instead of Ext.getStore(). It worked